# What big data solution can I use to process a huge number of input files?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, bigdata, amazon-sqs

I am currently searching for the best solution + environment for a problem I have. I'm simplifying the problem a bit, but basically:

1. I have a huge number of small files uploaded to Amazon S3.
2. I have a rule system that matches any input across all file content (including file names) and then outputs a verdict classifying each file. NOTE: I cannot combine the input files because I need an output for each input file.

I've reached the conclusion that Amazon EMR with MapReduce is not a good solution for this. I'm looking for a big data solution that is good at processing a large number of input files and performing a rule matching operation on the files, outputting a verdict per file. Probably will have to use ec2.

EDIT: clarified 2 above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with Hadoop is when you get a very large number of files that you do not combine with CombineFileInput format, it makes the job less efficient.

Spark doesnt seem to have a problem with this though, Ive had jobs run without problems with 10s of 1000s of files and output 10s of 1000s of files. Not tried to really push the limits, not sure if there even is one!

Comment: It seems like maybe I'm forcing the idea of MapReduce here. Also I don't think you can use Spark with EMR? Do you have any other suggestions for the problem? Is there a bid data solution designed to work with multiple input files?

Comment: Dont use EMR then, just use EC2 and slap on Ubuntu server 14.04